# Is there an autocomplete function for main body text in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, auto-completion

Commands can autocomplete, but ideally, I would have an extension that can also autocomplete main body text. I have this in VS Code, but I like the overleaf editor more. Does anyone know if such a tool or (chrome) extension exists?